# Accessing secure file in Azure DevOps pipeline in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to DevOps and trying to access the secure file via PowerShell script. Here is the scenario:

Agent I am using is ubuntu 18.04
I have uploaded my certificate as secure file and able to download when I am executing the pipeline. I have verified it by seeing the $(Agent.TempDirectory) content where certificate (.cer) is present.

Then I am running a PowerShell script which has below line of code:

```
$Certificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new('$(Agent.TempDirectory)/mycert.cer')
```

But this line always gives me the below error:

[image]

What is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro syntax `$()` will be expanded only in the template. If your script is stored in the file, you need to use environment variable: `$env:AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY`

```
$Certificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new("$env:AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY/mycert.cer")
```